# A lot of insertQuerys - efficiency

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledb

I have a static method that opens a connection to SQL Server, writes a log message and closes the connection.
I call this method plenty of times from the whole the code (every 2 sec on average).

The question is - is it efficient?
I thought maybe it would be better to accumulate some logs and insert them with one connection?

But then I'll have to save them somewhere (xml?), and this costs too.

So.. What is the efficient way to do this?
Write to an xml\file\whatever and then update in one connection with bulk
or open connection for any little update?

```
public static bool writeLog(string TaskName="MainApp", string LogMessage=null)      
{
    string logCmd = ...
    OleDbConnection conn = ...
    OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(logCmd,conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }                
    }
    return isSuccses;
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider http://logging.apache.org/log4net/ instead?

Comment: Nobody will ever give you the correct answer until you gather some stats and do experiments.

Comment: The OleDb provider is not the fastest. I wonder why you don't use a SqlConnection and the rest of the native provider.

Comment: I'll clarify the question:
write to xml\file and then update in one connection with bulk

OR

open connection for any little update?

Comment: Unfortunately the way you've written this question, the only correct answer is "it depends".  In our production system we have both kinds of applications - one that opens connection and writes an entry every time it needs to log something, and another that collects log data into a giant string and writes it once to the database asynchronously.  The former does nightly data batch processing and so performance is flexible, while the latter is a web service that is tuned for high performance/fast response times.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks for the answer. Can you please explain a little bit about your asynchronously solution ? how you design the giant string and how you restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what is your expectation of efficiency but here's a general comment.

Inserting a record every 2 seconds is certainly something SQL Server can handle without problems even if you open a connection every time. You insert one record at the time, there won't be even noticable locking problems, etc.

If you would change your architecture, it would make it more complex and harder to maintain data integrity (you would have to store the values in some sort of cache and make sure that this cache doesn't get lost, etc). This doesn't seem necessary in this case.

---

As an aside, you may want to switch to the native SQL Server provider and using `SQLConnection` for performance.

Comment: +1 without any other information to consider, writing log entries every two seconds is hardly a performance concern.

Answer (score 0):

no sql like mongo DB would be better alternative here.

Otherwise 2 sec is no big deal, if you are looking to avoid any kind of load on database, store all content in file and transfer them in batch during non peak hour.